# How to read a string backwards in SQL ? (not REVERSE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

So I have these two strings.

```
@a =  SALE:1:39
@b =  SALE:12
```

I have to compare both the string.
Comparison on:

```
LEFT part of @a = SALE:1
RIGHT Part of @a = 39

LEFT part of @b = SALE
RIGHT Part of @b = 12
```

What I have done so far is

```
RIGHT(@a, CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@a))-1)<br>
RIGHT(@b, CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@b))-1)<br>
LEFT(@a, CHARINDEX(':', @a)-1)<br>
LEFT(@b, CHARINDEX(':',@b)-1).<br>
```

RESULT

39 <-- LEFT @a
12 <-- LEFT @b
SALE <-- RIGHT @a, which should be ***SALE:1***
SALE <-- RIGHT @b
SALE:1:39
SALE:12

I want to split the string on the last occurrence of `:`

How to achieve that in MS SQL Server?

So basically what I am trying to achieve here is, I want to compare these two strings.

```
IF @a AND @b are non-numeric<br> THEN IF @a AND @b LIKE '%:%'
IF So Then is the left part of @a = left part of @b
IF YES Then is the Right part of @b = Right part of @a + 1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can help you but first you need to explain what you are trying to do more clearly.

Comment: So basically what I am trying to achieve here is, I want to compare these two strings. <br> IF @a AND @b are non-numeric<br> THEN IF @a AND @b LIKE '%:%'<br>IF So Then is the left part of @a = left part of @b<br>IF YES Then is the Right part of @b  = Right part of @a + 1<br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @a varchar (100) = 'SALE:1:39'
, @b varchar(100) = 'SALE:12'

select
LEFT(@a, len(@a) - charindex(':', REVERSE(@a))) LeftFromA
, RIGHT(@a, case when charindex(':', REVERSE(@a)) - 1 < 0 then 0 else charindex(':', REVERSE(@a)) - 1 end) RightFromA
, LEFT(@b, len(@b) - charindex(':', REVERSE(@b))) LeftFromB
, RIGHT(@b, case when charindex(':', REVERSE(@b)) - 1 < 0 then 0 else charindex(':', REVERSE(@b)) - 1 end) RightFromB
```